# vmware powercli

Tags: powershell, powercli

i want to create New vm's from muliple template's like windows 8,7 and more like that, also want to choose how many i need of that vm.

the full code is here:
[link to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/PSs5WRdU)

but the thing is i want to do multiple templates at once how can i do that?

i was thinking about an foreach($template in $template){do that}

then im doing template1,template2 but its giving me the error that its just template1,template2 instead of 2 diffrent templates dont know how to seperate that. i thought about the , but i dont know then.

Comment: You have multiple templates and want to create one virtual machine per template right?

Comment: i want to create muliple vms from a template and i want to use multiple templates for that

Comment: how its now working i can create multiple vm's but cant use multple template's
also ive used split for the , but the vm name doesnt change

Comment: Cant find how it needs to be still :(

Comment: Folks might look more closely if you edit the question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with full error text.

Comment: ive posted my full script in the question maybe you can do something with it to get it working

Comment: i want to output the only array value's that im sending with the parameter
link to pastebin
http://pastebin.com/ZHYWaK0k
so if i do Foo 3,4 i want to read the values that are in 3 and 4 how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, you have to specify one (and only one) template to create a new from template.

You can verify that by running the following command :

```
Get-Help New-VM -Parameter Template

-Template <Template>
    Specifies the virtual machine template you want to use for the creation of the new virtual machine. Passing values to this parameter through a pipeline is deprecated and will be disabled in a future release.

    Required?                    true
    Position?                    2
    Default value
    Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue)
    Accept wildcard characters?  true
```

As you can see , this -Template parameter takes only one object of the type [Template].
If it were able to take several, we would see :

```
-Template <Template[]>
```

But it is the same in the GUI anyway : in the vSphere client you have to choose only one template to create a VM from it.